Containerd, extend network interface/access to DIND container to perform docker pull
I have an unusual use case, for a number of reasons my company asked me to rewrite my application and deploy it using containerd on Kubernets.The app does something similar to Github Actions and Nektos Act using DIND.I managed to create my DIND container and start it
    container, err := cli.NewContainer(ctx, containerName,
        containerd.WithImage(image),
        containerd.WithNewSnapshot(containerName+"-snapshot", image),
        containerd.WithNewSpec(
            oci.WithImageConfig(image),
            oci.WithPrivileged,
            oci.WithEnv(containerEnv),
            oci.WithMounts(mnts),
        ),
    )


But once the application in the DIND container tries to perform a docker pull, I get the following error:
time="2024-08-01T12:44:17.563714641Z" level=warning msg="Error getting v2 registry: Get https://private-repo.local/v2/: dial tcp: lookup private-repo.local on \[::1\]:53: read udp \[::1\]:34343-\>\[::1\]:53: read: connection refused"
time="2024-08-01T12:44:17.563756965Z" level=info msg="Attempting next endpoint for pull after error: Get https://private-repo.local/v2/: dial tcp: lookup private-repo.local on \[::1\]:53: read udp \[::1\]:34343-\>\[::1\]:53: read: connection refused"
time="2024-08-01T12:44:17.563816052Z" level=error msg="Handler for POST /v1.40/images/create returned error: Get https://private-repo.local/v2/: dial tcp: lookup private-repo.local on \[::1\]:53: read udp \[::1\]:34343-\>\[::1\]:53: read: connection refused"

Can someone help me understand how to exted access to the host network interface and set a specific DNS server ?
I researched the Github project moby/moby and perform multiple keyword searches on containerd/containerd without any success.

If you're trying to deploy this on Kubernetes I would use the native Kubernetes API.  Do not try to use any particular container runtime API (remove the direct mentions of containerd) and do not try to run a nested Docker daemon.  You also shouldn't need host networking, in any environment, and might be prohibited from using it in Kubernetes.
